# Mongoose/MongoDB throwing duplicate key error on save?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

According to [MongoDB's documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/) a call to `save` will create a new document, or update an existing document if `_id` is provided.  Mongoose's documentation is [less detailed](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) and does not go into whether it will insert or update.

I am attempting to use Mongoose's `save` function to update a document, but I keep getting the error:

> {"error":{"name":"MongoError","code":11000,"err":"insertDocument ::
>   caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index:
>   staging.participants.$_id _  dup key: { :
>   ObjectId('5515a34ed65073ec234b5c5f') }"}}

Does Mongoose's `save` function perform an upsert like MongoDB's `save` function or is it just performing an insert?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

What defines whether the `save` will be an insert or an update is the `isNew` flag, as you can [see here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/model.js#L91).

This flag is set automatically to `false` when the document instance is returned from a `find` query (or any of its variations). If you are instantiating the document manually, try setting this flag to false before saving it:

```
var instance = new Model({ '_id': '...', field: '...' });
instance.isNew = false;
instance.save(function(err) { /* ... */ });
```

There is also an `init` function, that will initialize the document and [automatically set `isNew` to `false`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/lib/document.js#L261):

```
var data = { '_id': '...', field: '...' };
var instance = new Model();
instance.init(data, {}, function(err) {
    instance.save(function(err) { /* ... */ })
});
```