# save() on MongoTemplate return duplicate key error when replace

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I want to update my document using save() method by including the id but got an error `E11000 duplicate key error collection: db.document index: _id_ dup key: { _id: ObjectId`.

I try to update my document using update() but it will take too much effort and much possible error because my document has a lot of fields that need to be handled.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29475118/mongoose-mongodb-throwing-duplicate-key-error-on-save?rq=2

Comment: I don't understand the objection in the second paragraph. You can use update modifiers in the update command to only modify the fields that you want to change rather than specifying all of them, that's best practice in fact

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @user20042973 sure, agree with that. previously i just try and wondering is there sort way to just replace all field in my mongo document except the _ID use save() method.